# Need array that consists of parent and child relations in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Hi there I have an array which consists of parent and child relations.

```
$data = array(
677 => 678
678 => 679
679 => 880
880 => 881
881 => 882
882 => 883
883 => 884);
```

Here values are main article id and values are those child ids. went this way

```
$k = [];
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
  $k[$key][$val] = $data[$val];
}
```

But my result is $k

```
Array
(
  [677] => Array
  (
    [678] => 679
  )
    [678] => Array
  (
    [679] => 880
  )
    [679] => Array
  (
    [880] => 881
  )
    [880] => Array
  (
    [881] => 882
  )
    [881] => Array
  (
    [882] => 883
  )
    [882] => Array
  (
    [883] => 884
  )
    [883] => Array
  (
    [884] => 
  )
)
```

But I need something like

```
677 => [
  678 => [
    679 => [
      880 => [
        881 => [
          882 => [
            883 => [
              884
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Tried in multiple ways and there is something I am missing and need someones help in solving this. in foreach only remaining array keys should be added as values of some value. Thanks in advance

```
[
  [677] => [
    [id] => 677
    [child] => [
      [id] => 678
      [child] => [
        [id] => 679
        [child] => [
          [id] => 880
          [child] => [
            [id] => 881
            [child] => [
              [id] => 882
              [child] => [
                [id] => 883
                [child] => 884
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: `677 => ,` is not valid PHP to begin with. You can not write an array definition, where an element has not value whatsoever. You need to put `0` or `NULL` for the items that do not have a parent.

Comment: @nice_dev: sorry I forgot to keep code. I added my code above. please check. I am missing something, but couldnt get that.

Comment: @CBroe. Yup I edited it and swapped for perfect array to get with.

Comment: Looks like you swapped around what the item and what the parent is as well now? Why? That makes determining which element is actually the top-most one harder now ... (Unless there is a guaranteed order of those elements in your array to begin with?)

Comment: @CBroe - Left side ones are main articles and right ones are child id

Comment: So each article will never be able to have more than one child?

Comment: Yes. only one child for an article

Comment: As I said, you would have to first of all determine now, which element is actually the top-most one. (Or can that actually be determine from the order - _first_ array item, will also always be the top-most one?) And after that, you'll probably need either a recursive function, or something that works with references.

Comment: 677 is parent of all ids. in it it have child and subchilds added. Adding sample output. not exactly but something like above last code.

Comment: _"677 is parent of all ids."_ - yes, but how do you _know_ that? If it can not be automatically inferred by the _order_ of those items, then you would have to determine it first, by checking which key does not occur as a value. Why have you moved away from the format that you had initially shown, that was a bit more suitable for such things to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if the order of your IDs are in fact  *ordered* meaning, parent before child fashion, then you can do the below:

- We use references to keep track of previous parent array which gives us the ability to edit the current array in place.
- If the previous key's value matches the current key, it means the current key(which was the previous value) has a child. We use this to decide whether it is going to be an array key or value.
- For the next iteration, catch hold of the reference of the current child array and repeat the same steps.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$result = [];
$prev = &$result;

foreach($data as $key => $val){
  $prevKey = $prev[0] ?? -1;
  if($prevKey === $key){
    $prev = [ $key  => [ $val ] ];
  }else{
    $prev[ $key ] = [ $val ];
  }
  
  $prev = &$prev[ $key ];
}

print_r($result);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yhf8vc3a)

---

**Update:**

Modified with `id` and `child` keys' format making the code more concise.

```
<?php

$result = [];
$prev = &$result;

foreach($data as $key => $val){
  $prev = ['id' => $key, 'child' => []];
  $prev = &$prev['child'];
}

$prev = ['id' => $val, 'child' => [] ];

print_r($result);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yhfbtund)